# cannot find column or the user-defined function or aggregate, or the name is ambigous

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am getting this error when trying to INNER JOIN 2 tables.

"cannot find column "TE" or the user-defined function or aggregate "TE.UserID", or the name is ambigous"

Any ideas?

I've tried adding the table name to the Select statement like below.  That actually ran the query in SQL Server.  But it doesn't do anything for Python ODBC.

```
"Select TP.UserID, Phone "
```

But that doesn't help.

```
userid = 'dd88'

try:
    connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=MyServerName;Database=MyDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
    sqlstate = ex.args[0]
    if sqlstate == '28000':
        print("You do not have access.") 
cursor = connection.cursor() 
SQLCommand = ("SELECT UserID, Phone "
    "FROM dbo.SEC_UserProfile as TP INNER JOIN dbo.SEC_User as TE "
    "ON TP.UserID = TE.UserID "
    "(nolock)"
    "WHERE UserID LIKE ?")
Values = ['%' + userid + '%']
cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
results = cursor.fetchone()
if results:
    print(connections + " " + str(results[0]) + " " + str(results[1])) # enters results in entry
    connection.close()
else:
    print(connections + " - NO")
    connection.close()
```

UserID is in both tables.

Comment: try adding the table names everywhere... for instance, in the where clause as well.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Please be careful using NOLOCK. It has a lot of fun things most people don't know about. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And if you insist on using at least use the correct syntax. Omitting the WITH keyword has been deprecated in query hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well one problem is you have `(nolock)` in the wrong place.   It should immediately follow a table alias, not the join condition:

Also don't you need to add concatenation operators when building this SQLCommand string?   I've never used Python, but if this were .net code, it wouldn't even compile.

```
SQLCommand = ("SELECT TP.UserID, Phone " +
    "FROM dbo.SEC_UserProfile as TP (nolock) INNER JOIN dbo.SEC_User as TE (nolock)" +
    "ON TP.UserID = TE.UserID " +
    "WHERE TP.UserID LIKE ?")
```

Comment: I did have to add TP.UserID in the SELECT statement, but adjusting the nolock worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your sql statement by defining from which table you need UserID in select and where clauses, like:

```
SQLCommand = ("SELECT TP.UserID, Phone "
    "FROM dbo.SEC_UserProfile as TP (nolock) INNER JOIN dbo.SEC_User as TE "
    "ON TP.UserID = TE.UserID "
    "WHERE TP.UserID LIKE ?")
```

@TabAlleman is right, the place of (nolock) was not correct. Updated my answer.